# *UnicodeEncodeError from update_contenttypes when trying to migrate

Tags: django, unicode, migrate

I'm getting a `UnicodeEncodeError` when trying to migrate my project on the server.

This is the error message :

```
File "/home/elandem/.virtualenvs/v-edem/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/management.py", line 73, in update_contenttypes
Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: """ % content_type_display)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 98: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And [here](https://dpaste.de/R9we) is the full traceback.

It seems to come from **update_contenttypes**, but it's not pointing at any specific part of my app. Can someone shine a light on where this might be coming from ?

Comment: post your Models here.

Comment: @wolendranh should I post all of my models ? I have quite a few... anything in particular we are looking for ?

Comment: Did you run migration for the first time for this project?